# I need help to get crontab working in Xubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: scripts, xubuntu, cron

I have set a crontab job like this :

```
@reboot  xmodmap -e \"keycode 105=Delete\"
@reboot  xmodmap -e \"keycode 66=Home\"
```

and saved on default directory suggested by NANO (`/tmp/..../.../cron`), but it's not working. I can list cron job, cron service is running, the output of `journalctl -b 0 _SYSTEMD_UNIT=cron.service` displays the jobs without errors and so on.  Besides that, I  also can't run a script at boot: `@reboot /home/user/scripts/myscript.sh`

Why is `cron` not working as I expect?

Comment: Check out some details on [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) and how others solve similar problems to your own.

Comment: @earthmeLon xmodmap is not the problem. crontab is the problem, it's not working.

Comment: why i got -1?? maybe it's a misunderstanding, I have read plenty of tutorials on how to get xmodmap working automatically from boot (start up) and none of them work ! Lets suppose set a script to run at boot time from crontab also it's not working( and it apply to any script on user/home directory or root) , something is missing.

Answer (score 3):

xmodmap modifies the keycode mapping for the current session. So if you run it in crontab, it opens a session, modifies the mapping and closes the session again - and its effect is gone.

You should instead run the xmodmap commands in your profile `$HOME/.profile` (or in your `$HOME/.xinitrc` if you are starting the X session only at login).

`man xmodmap` says:

> It is usually run from the user's session startup script to configure
>   the keyboard according to personal tastes.

Comment: the problem is not xmodmap, THE PROBLEM is crontab, I also can not run a script at boot from crontab. I have created an alias in .bashrc to execute  xmodmap -e \"keycode 105=Delete\"    and it works. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`man cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), or other examples on the Internet.  I believe that the problem you are having is you're not using the full path the the binaries.

```bsh
| melon@pc ~>$ which xmodmap
/usr/bin/xmodmap
```

In your `cron -e`, instead of `xmodmap`, you would put `/usr/bin/xmodmap`.

But, even with this change, you won't see any key changes.

---

Linux is great in that it provides various solutions to problems, but look into how others have solved similar problems.  For example, `xmodmap` is typically invoked in `.xinitrc`, which is executed when your X session starts.  `xmodmap` really won't work the way you're trying, at least for your normal user.

Since you're interested in `xmodmap`, I recommend you look at [documentation and examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) and forget about `cron` completely for this current issue.

If you are unwilling to look at documentation and other examples, or want a real understanding of how things work, you can look up the `man` pages:

```
XMODMAP(1)                            General Commands Manual                            XMODMAP(1)

NAME
       xmodmap - utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X

SYNOPSIS
       xmodmap [-options ...] [filename]

DESCRIPTION
       The  xmodmap  program is used to edit and display the keyboard modifier map and keymap table
       that are used by client applications to convert event keycodes into keysyms.  It is  usually
       run  from  the user's session startup script to configure the keyboard according to personal
       tastes.
```

This last sentence has the answers to your problem.

At this point, you don't know if `cron` isn't working (this is your suspicion), or if `xmodmap` fired, but you don't see the effects.  The latter is the likely scenario.  Your user needs to execute `xmodmap` within the current X session for `xmodmap` changes to be effective.

---

Once you get `xmodmap` working without `cron`, you can solve the next problem.  As mentioned earlier, you need full system paths, but you also need to tell `cron` **how** to run the file.  You've simply pointed to the file, which works on your terminal, as it uses the shebang/interpreter (ie: `#!/bin/bash`).  So, for `cron` to run a `bash` file...

```bsh
| melon@nifflheim ~>$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash
| melon@nifflheim ~>$ crontab -e
...
@reboot /usr/bin/bash /home/user/scripts/myscript.sh
```

Though, do you really want `root` running a script found in your user directory?  With what you've learned so far, maybe you add `/usr/bin/bash /home/user/scripts/myscript.sh` (or `source` it) in `~/.xinitrc` instead ^_~.

Comment: nice from you explaining how it should work, now I can try your suggestions, sometimes I got really confused to figure out how I should set xmodmap to work, and for crontab, believe me : it is the first time I try to set a cronjob, I have never done it before. thks. vladi